# Unable to keep array element downcase that is found in `include?`

Tags: ruby

I have requirements with my `Title` class as below.

1. Take an all-lower-case string like `"the united states"` and make the initial letter in each word capitalized (`"The United States"`).
2. Take a camel case string like `"ThE UnIted STatEs"` and make it `"The United States"`.

The following code satisfies them:

```
class Title
  attr_accessor :string
  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end
  def fix
    string2 = string.split(" ").map{ |string| string.capitalize }.join(" ")
  end
end
```

I added another condition:

3. If the string is `"the"`, `"The"`, `"of"`, `"Of"`, it does not capitalize it.

The attempt to modify `fix` with `map` logic as below did not work:

```
class Title
  def fix
    string2 = string.split(" ").map{ |string| string.capitalize }.join(" ")
    string2.split(" ").map{ |string| (string.include?("of","Of","the","The") ?   string.downcase : string.capitalize) }.join(" ")
  end
end
#=> Error:  wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Is there another way I can implement this logic? I'm not sure why this isn't working for me. Can anyone offer any assistance/guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String#include](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) only takes one argument, that's where the ArgumentError is coming from.  Instead you could do something like:

```
[8] pry(main)> prepositions = ["of", "Of", "the", "The"]
=> ["of", "Of", "the", "The"]
[9] pry(main)> string2.split(" ").map{ |string| prepositions.include?(string) ? string.downcase : string.capitalize }.join(" ")
=> "of Thy Self In the Capital"
```

I prefer the above, it allows you to easily keep a list of words that are outside the normal capitalization method.  It's easy to read, easy to add to etc.  That said, you can use case insensitive regex with match as well:

```
string2.split(" ").map{ |string| string.match(/(the)|(of)/i) ? string.downcase : string.capitalize }.join(" ")
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony that clears up a lot for me in how I can use the map method to my full advantage in Ruby.  The pry(main) structure seems better for code management.  Do I need to add anything else to my Title class to use this method?  The second one works smoothly of course!

Answer (score 1):

**Use `gsub`**

You don't need to convert the string to an array of words, map the words, then `join`. Instead, just use the form of [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a block.

```
Little Words
```

You said you do not want to capitalize certain words. Editors often refer to such words as ["little words"](http://reword.ca/blog/self-editing-tip-little-words-that-dont-need-to-be-there/). Let's define a few:

```
LITTLE_WORDS = %w{ the of for a an or and }
  #=> ["the", "of", "for", "a", "an", "or", "and"]
```

**Code**

I assume that all little words encountered are be downcased, and all other words are to be downcased and capitalized. We can do that thus:

```
def fix(str)
  str.gsub(/\w+/) do |w|
    if LITTLE_WORDS.include?(w.downcase)
      w.downcase
    else
      w.capitalize
    end
  end
end
```

**Examples**

Let's try it:

```
fix("days of wine aNd roses") #=> "Days of Wine and Roses"
fix("of mice and meN")        #=> "of Mice and Men"
```

Hmmm. A bit of a problem with the second example. Presumably, we should capitalize the first word regardless of whether it's a little word. There are various ways to do that.

**#1 Capitalize the first word after modifying all words**

```
def fix(str)
  str.gsub(/\w+/) do |w|
    if LITTLE_WORDS.include?(w.downcase)
      w.downcase
    else
      w.capitalize
    end
  end.sub(/^(\w+)/) { |s| s.capitalize }
end

fix("of mice and men")
  #=> "Of Mice and Men"
```

Notice that I've introduced a capture group in the regex. Alternatively, you could change the penultimate line to:

```
end.sub(/^(\w+)/) { $1.capitalize }
```

**#2 Set a flag**

```
def fix(str)
  first_word = true
  str.gsub(/\w+/) do |w|
    if LITTLE_WORDS.include?(w.downcase) && !first_word
      w.downcase
    else
      first_word = false
      w.capitalize
    end
  end
end

fix("of mice and men")
  #=> "Of Mice and Men"
```

**#3 Use an index**

```
def fix(str)
  str.gsub(/\w+/).with_index do |w,i|
    if LITTLE_WORDS.include?(w.downcase) && i > 0
      w.downcase
    else
      w.capitalize
    end
  end
end

fix("of mice and men")
  #=> "Of Mice and Men"
```

**#4 Modify the regex**

```
def fix(str)
  str.gsub(/(^\w+)|\w+/) do |w|
    if $1.nil? && LITTLE_WORDS.include?(w.downcase) 
      w.downcase
    else
      w.capitalize
    end
  end
end

fix("of mice and men")
  #=> "Of Mice and Men"
```

**More problems**

Now we need just fix:

```
fix("I bought an iPhone and a TV")
  #=> "I Bought an Iphone and a Tv"
```