# how to capitalize elements in array, with exceptions [ruby]

Tags: ruby

I'm new to programming, and self-teaching I'm trying to write a program that takes a string and capitalizes every word in the string. But, to exclude certain words such as "and, of, the, a". The purpose is to fix a broken string and return a title like string.

Here's what I have so far.

```
class Title
  attr_accessor :string, :fix
  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def fix
    str = []
    final = []
    string.downcase
    string[0].capitalize
    str = string.split
    str.each_with_index do |s, x|
      if s == "and"
        final << s
      elsif s == "of"
        final << s
      elsif s == "a"
        final << s
      elsif s == "the" && x != 0
        final << s
      else
        final << s.capitalize
      end
    end
    string = final.join(' ')
    return string
  end
end
```

I'm getting the error that I'm capitalizing every single word, and the program is ignoring the exceptions that I want.

Comment: `string.downcase` returns a new string (which you ignore in your code) and should be `string.downcase!` if you want to change the original instead. That may explain some of your problems, especially if you start with "ALL CAPS" style string. It may be worth giving some examples of your failing inputs and the resulting output to demonstrate the fault in the question.

Comment: I would also recommend `Array#include?` eg. `do_not_capitalize = ['and','of','a', the]; final << do_not_capitalize.include?(s) ? s : s.capitalize` needs handling for "the" but you get the idea. It will eliminate the `if..elsif` and make it more flexible in the future.

Comment: And your `fix` method overrides the `fix` method created by `attr_accessor :fix`. Do you need `attr_accessor` at all here?

Comment: Are you sure you want to exclude those words?

Comment: See [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400983/unable-to-keep-array-element-downcase-that-is-found-in-include).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking something like this

```
class Title
  attr_accessor :string
  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def fix
    filtered_string = string.split.select{ |a| !["and", "of", "the", "a"].include? a }
    title = filtered_string.map{ |a| a.capitalize }.join(" ")
  end
end
```

First you filter out excluded words and then join capitalized words to title.
You don't need `attr_accessor :fix` because fix is defined as public method.

Comment: This will actually *remove* the excepted words in the output of `fix`, I think OP would like to still have them, but not captialized. You could achieve that by having your test inside the `map`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class Titlizer
  BLACK_LIST = %w(and of the a)

  def initialize(sentence)
    @sentence = sentence
  end

  def title
    capitalized.join(" ").capitalize
  end

  private

  def capitalized
    words.map do |word|
      if should_capitalize?(word)
        word.capitalize
      else
        word
      end
    end
  end

  def words
    @sentence.split
  end

  def should_capitalize?(word)
    !BLACK_LIST.include?(word)
  end
end
```